# What exactly does it mean that a content type is "creatable" (or not) in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

When defining a content type in Orchard, there's the choice of making it "creatable" or not. As far as I can see, creatable types are available for creation (and editing) via the admin dashboard. A side effect seems to be that if a type is not creatable, even existing items of that type cannot be edited (they are not listed under "Content" at all), which I find a bit counterintuitive.

Are there other implications of marking a content type as **not creatable**, other than visibility in the admin dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that it appears under the "New" admin menu item and the Content management screen. That is all. That's what it means.

Non-creatable types are just as editable as any other type, but you need to provide your own admin link for them.

Comment: Actually it seems that content types that are not creatable are not visible in the ContentPicker field either. Odd.

Comment: No, that's by design. Otherwise, you'd see things like widgets and users appear there, which wouldn't make much sense in most case. The content picker is extensible however, and recently (in 1.x, not yet released) gained the ability to specify what content types you want to show there.

Comment: Any idea when this 1.x version will be released? And until then, in what way is the content picker extensible? I really need to be able to "lock it down" to a specific content type (that is not creatable)... I'm currently experimenting with a modified content picker that provides this option, but if it's going to be included in the standard picker soon, I'd rather use that of course.

Comment: No, we haven't set a date. Currently it already is extensible: you can add your own tabs.